# Compare lasso regression models

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, lasso

I have a continuous outcome variable and several different `lasso` models to predict the outcome. Something like

```
outcome ~ explain1 + explain2 + confounders
outcome ~ explain3 + explain4 + confounders
outcome ~ explain1 + explain2 + explain3 + explain4 + confounders
```

I know that I can calculate several goodness of fit measures like [PRESS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRESS_statistic) or just the [mean square error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error). And models with lower PRESS/MSE predict the outcome more accurately. But how can I quantify this difference, ideally with a p-value, which indicates if one model is significantly better than the other?

For "normal" regression models I could use anova, but this doesn't seem to work for lasso models (at least in `R`).

Comment: Why doesn't it work?   LASSO is a method of generating models. Once they are generated, you can do whatever you like with them.  But, really, if you believe in LASSO then why do you want to use ANOVA on the results?

Comment: Why "believe in lasso"...? And how does this depend on ANOVA?

Comment: If you think LASSO works, then it gives you the best model and you don't need ANOVA, but it will work exactly the same with LASSO models as with others, because LASSO gives the same sort of models as any other method.

Comment: I think it's kind of naive to just believe that lasso gives me the best model without further testing. Apart from that: My aim is to see if and how much additional explanatory variables improve the prediction.

Comment: The Lasso is designed to work better than other selection models. And ANOVA will work on any models.

Comment: Could you explain how you obtained 3 different models (and, in particular, the first 2 models with the same number of explanatory variables but no overlap of explanatory variables) by applying LASSO to the same data set?